# How to sort multidimensional array by multiple column index

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to sort multidimensional array by multiple column index.

For example, I have below test data,

```
var source = [
  ["Jack","A","B1", 4],
  ["AVicky","M", "B2", 2],
  ["AVicky","F", "B3", 3],
];
```

I want to sort source based on dynamic column index, like sometime I want to sort based on first+second, next time, I may want to sort by first+second+three.

Currently, I tried code below, but, it will only sort based on specific column index.

```
var source = [
  ["Jack","A","B1", 4],
  ["AVicky","M", "B2", 2],
  ["AVicky","F", "B3", 3],
];
var target = [  
  ["Tom","M", "B3", 2],
  ["Jack","F", "B1", 1],
  ["Cindy","F", "B3", 3],
];
var keyIndexs = [0,1];
var same = [];
//order rows
var sourceOrder =  source
keyIndexs.forEach(i => sourceOrder = sortByColumn(sourceOrder, i)) ;
console.log(sourceOrder);
for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i ++){
  //console.log(ContainsRow(source[i], target));
  if(ContainsRow(source[i], target)){
    same.push(source[i]);
  }
}
console.log(same);

function CompareRow(source:any[], target:any[]):boolean{
  return JSON.stringify(source) === JSON.stringify(target);
}

function ContainsRow(source:any[], target: any[][]):boolean{
  for(var i = 0; i <target.length; i ++){
    if(CompareRow(source, target[i])){
      return true;
    }
  } 
  return false;
}

function sortByColumn(a, colIndex){
  a.sort(sortFunction);
  function sortFunction(a, b) {
      if (a[colIndex] === b[colIndex]) {
          return 0;
      }
      else {
          return (a[colIndex] < b[colIndex]) ? -1 : 1;
      }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const sortCompareFn = sortArr => (a, b) => {
  const getValue = v => sortArr.reduce((a, c) => a + v[c], '')
  const aValue = getValue(a)
  const bValue = getValue(b)
  return typeof aValue === 'string'
    ? aValue.localeCompare(bValue)
    : aValue - bValue
}

const source = [
  ["Jack","A","B1", 4],
  ["AVicky","M", "B2", 2],
  ["AVicky","F", "B3", 3],
]

const sortArr1 = [1]
const result1 = source.sort(sortCompareFn(sortArr1))
console.log('result1:', result1)

const sortArr23 = [2, 3]
const result23 = source.sort(sortCompareFn(sortArr23))
console.log('result23:', result23)

const sortArr3 = [3]
const result3 = source.sort(sortCompareFn(sortArr3))
console.log('result3:', result3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it works great, one more question, is it possible to convert `sortCompareFn` to a function defination like my `sortByColumn`